# Trying to get property on non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with this line of codes.

```
foreach ($entity as $info) {
    $ent_login = Entity::select('loginid')->where('entityid', $info->entityid)->first();
    $ent_email = User::select('email')->where('loginid', $ent_login->loginid)->first();
    $info->basic_email = $ent_email->email;
}
```

I tried runnig this in my local but it's working. When I tried pushing it on the server it keeps saying `Trying to get property 'email' of non-object` on the last line. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your local database probably has records in the `users`(used by `User` class), while the users table in production doesn't have  these. Check that `loginid` in production database.

Comment: Thank you for answering but the loginid is also present on the database on the server-side.

Comment: I am not saying about the column, about the record. Check the records working in your local table also exists in production table. User::select... returns null which means there is no matching record(s) in production table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the loop iteration that fails:

1. Check if `$ent_login->loginid` is `null`;
2. If not, check if your query is returning records. `SELECT * from users WHERE loginid = {{$ent_login->loginid}}`;

Answer (score 0):

Note that `$ent_email` needs to be an Array

```
 foreach ($entity as $info) {
     $ent_login = Entity::select('loginid')->where('entityid', $info->entityid)->first();
     $ent_email = User::select('email')->where('loginid', $ent_login->loginid)->toArray();

    $info->basic_email = $ent_email[email];
 }
```